# Fill in the cells from start and end date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

just want to check if it is possible to fill the cell base on the dates, for example, in columns A and B, I have from - to date, and in column E, I have a date list, and in column F, I would like to fill in "holiday" which the dates are within columns A and B, is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
=IF(SUM((E2 >= $A$2:$A$3)*(E2 <= $B$2:$B$3)),"Holiday","")
```

which will give:

[image]